# The convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis

if $\sup_{a\in I}\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(a)<C,$ for $\forall \epsilon>0,$ if there is a $N>0$, such that 
$\sup_{a\in I}\sum_{i=N}^\infty a_i(a)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Do you mean "is there a $N$" instead of "if there is a $N$"?

Comment: What is $I$? Why do you say that $\sup:{a\in I}\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(a)<C$, for $\forall\epsilon>0$ when there is no $\epsilon$ in $\sup:{a\in I}\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(a)<C$?

Comment: @user47774 Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $I = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $a_i(j) = 1$ if and only if $i=j$ (and $a_i(j) = 0$ otherwise). Then, $\sup_{a\in I} \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(a) = 1$ but for $\epsilon = .5$ (for example), for any $N$ and any $a > N$, $\sum_{i=N}^\infty a_i(a) = 1 > \epsilon$.